# Applescript Handler

Tags: applescript

I am using the below script for few months. It ask the user to select from the list and copy paste the text in MS Word and run some VB Macro and save the file as Text file.

```
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder "Test" of desktop) then make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"Test"}
end tell
set desktopTestFolder to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Test:"
set mychoice to (choose from list {"PS List", "AA Table", "PS Legend", "PO Chart", "MD"} with prompt "Please select which sound you like best" default items "None" OK button name {"Play"} cancel button name {"Cancel"})
if mychoice is false then error number -128 -- user canceled

    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        set theContent to content of text object of selection
        copy object text object of selection
        set newDoc to make new document
        delay 2
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Microsoft Word"
                keystroke "v" using command down
            end tell
        end tell
        run VB macro macro name "Normal.NewMacros.Clean"
        run VB macro macro name "Normal.Module9.bold"

        save as newDoc file format format Unicode text file name (desktopTestFolder & mychoice & ".txt")
        close document 1 saving no
    end tell
```

But when I try it to put in an handler it not works. What I have tried is:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder "Test" of desktop) then make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"Test"}
end tell
set desktopTestFolder to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Test:"
set mychoice to (choose from list {"PS List", "AA Table", "PS Legend", "PO Chart", "MD"} with prompt "Please select which sound you like best" default items "None" OK button name {"Play"} cancel button name {"Cancel"})
if mychoice is false then error number -128 -- user canceled

set mychoice to mychoice as text
if mychoice is equal to "PS List" then
    handler1()
else
    handler2()
end if
on handler1()
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        set theContent to content of text object of selection
        copy object text object of selection
        set newDoc to make new document
        delay 2
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Microsoft Word"
                keystroke "v" using command down
            end tell
        end tell
        run VB macro macro name "Normal.NewMacros.EDCleanup1"
        run VB macro macro name "Normal.Module9.bold"

        save as newDoc file format format Unicode text file name (desktopTestFolder & mychoice & ".txt")
        close document 1 saving no
    end tell
end handler1

on handler2()
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        run VB macro macro name "Normal.NewMacros.EDCleanup1"
        run VB macro macro name "Normal.Module9.bold"

        save as newDoc file format format Unicode text file name (desktopTestFolder & mychoice & ".txt")
        close document 1 saving no
    end tell
end handler2
```

Please let me know, Where I am wrong?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what result you get when you say "it not works". Do you get an error? Do you get nothing? Do you get the same result when you select "PS List" versus the others?

The error I see is that you never bring Microsoft Word to the front. This is necessary for when you're using UI scripting and the keystroke command. Add 'activate' to your Word tell blocks.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    set theContent to content of text object of selection
    …
```

Also, yes, your variable desktopTestFolder loses scope. You can make the variable a global property by placing this at the front of your script:

```
property desktopTestFolder: ""
```

Comment: I added 'activate' to my Word tell blocks. Then also it throws an error "The variable desktopTestFolder is not defined."

Comment: Yes, inside a handler, the variable does not keep the same value. See my edit to my answer.